# Round up and round down of a given number to the multiples of floating poing number in python

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to extract the round up and round down of given values to the nearest 0.25 multiples. I have tried using round, ceil and floor functions but not getting the desired output. Is there any other function I can use to achieve the expected output shared in the below code snippet.

```
import math
x=[0.14,2.31,1.56,1.98,0.12,0.11,0.13,0.25]
lup=[]
ldown=[]
base=0.25
for i in x:
    x1= base*(round(float(i/base)))
    x2= base*(math.floor(float(i/base)))
    lup.append(x1)
    ldown.append(x2)
    # print(F"value:{i},fraction:{float(i/base)},fround:{round(float(i/base))},lup:{x1},ldown:{x2}")
print(F"lup={lup}")
print(F"ldown={ldown}")
```

expected output:

```
    lup = [0.25,2.5,1.75,2.0,0.25,0.25,0.25]
    ldown=[0,2.25,1.5,1.75,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.25]
```

obtained output:

```
lup=[0.25, 2.25, 1.5, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25, 0.25]
ldown=[0.0, 2.25, 1.5, 1.75, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.25]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `math.ceil`(The opposite of `math.floor`) instead of `math.round`:

```
x1= base*(math.ceil(float(i/base)))
```